# NSFetchedResultsController reinserts table view rows after deletion in iOS 6, iOS 7 works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using a pretty basic implementation of Core Data to store some objects in my app. The code is pretty much boiler plate code that Xcode creates as the model is as simple as they get (don't even have any relationships, just stand alone managed objects).

Everything works fine in iOS7, but in iOS 6 when deleting an object in the table view iOS removes the rows, then the fetchedResultsController immediately does a NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert and adds the deleted objects back to the table view.

If I navigate away from the table view and then back to it the rows are gone confirming they are deleted, but why is the controller calling NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert in iOS 6? I can confirm this is not even called in iOS 7 at all.

I've created a blank app in Xcode to compare the code to mine to make sure I didn't mess something up and the code is identical as I can see it. Can anyone explain this problem? I've not used Core Data before so I may be missing something obvious.

The only once difference in my code is that when I delete an object I also delete a jpg in the documents directory if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

After typing this post up I was thinking about how I was removing the image referenced in the object. I had a method within the managed object for doing this, after removing this for testing it appears that as the object was still working to do this the object could not be immediately deleted and the fetched results controller was adding the objects back to the table view. I added a method to remove the referenced image elsewhere within the TableView controller the problem was resolved. Posting this anyway in case anyone else has a similar problem and also because someone may have some feedback about better ways to handle this.